# How to upgrade a io.stringio to file as w

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, stringio

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#text-i-o says that
[io.Stringio](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.StringIO) is created inside of an open() file object. If I want to
start with a Stringio and then flush it into a file object how would I
do that? Obviously I could just open the new file object and then
write the Stringio to the object, but is there a cleaner way?

```py
from io import *

buf = StringIO() 
buf.write('here is my text in stringio')
buf.flush('filename')
buf.close()
```

Other than

```py
buf = StringIO() 
buf.write('here is my text in stringio')
with open('filename', 'w') as fo:
    buf.seek(0)
    fo.write(buf.read())
buf.close()
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: May I ask why? The entire point of `StringIO` is to fake a file object. If you know you are going to work with an actual file, why bother with `StringIO` to begin with?

Comment: @DeepSpace I have a part of a program set up to write to a file, but I also need it's out put for `_io.TextIOWrapper`, so if I can generalize the function that feeds both I don't have to worry about creating a file to keep the function happy when it might just be sent to TextIO anyway. I then won't have to delete the make function happy file either.